# Line break doesn't work at the end of while loop

Tags: php, fpdf

I recently started to use FPDF as a solution to export some data from sql to pdf.
This is my attempt to display a while loop. The only problem is with the line break at the end.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID ASC";
$items = mysql_query($sql);
while ($get = mysql_fetch_array($items)):

    $pdf->SetXY (10,130);
    $pdf->SetFontSize(12);
    $txt="<b>Item 1</b>: $get[NAME]";
    $pdf->WriteHTML(utf8_decode($txt));

    $pdf->SetXY (10,135);
    $pdf->SetFontSize(12);
    $txt="<b>Item 2</b>: $get[CITY]";
    $pdf->WriteHTML(utf8_decode($txt));

    $pdf->Ln(30);
endwhile;
```

Any solution to separate the result with some space?

Comment: Have you tried PHP_EOL?

Comment: No. Can you tell me moe about this?

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: you can you `/n/r` to use new line new row